# How to acess structure from an instance of templated class implementing an interface

Tags: c++, c++11

I basically have  2 questions based on my below code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    virtual int GetOperation() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Util : public Interface
{
   public:
    Util ();
    virtual ~Util (){}
    virtual int GetOperation() const override;
    T GetFields() ;
   private:
    int index;
    int operation;
    T mfield;
};

class A 
{
   public:
    A(){}
    int noOfPkts;
};
template <class T>
Util<T>::Util()
{
}

template <class T>
int Util<T>::GetOperation() const
{
    return operation;
}
template <class T>
T Util<T>::GetFields() 
{
    return mfield;
}


int main()
{
auto sn = std::make_unique <Util<A>>();
//sn->GetFields().noOfPkts = 10;
}
```

If I uncomment the code I get compilation error:

```
$ c++ -std=c++14 try51.cpp
try51.cpp: In function 'int main()':
try51.cpp:51:26: error: using temporary as lvalue [-fpermissive]
 sn->GetFields().noOfPkts = 10;
```

Secondly I actually want to implement within the interface a method that will return the template class fields structure like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~Interface() = default;
    virtual int GetOperation() const = 0;
    virtual struct Fields* GetFields() const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Util : public Interface
{
   public:
    Util ();
    virtual ~Util (){}
    virtual int GetOperation() const override;
    virtual struct Fields* GetFields() const override;
   private:
    int index;
    int operation;
    T mfield;
};

class A 
{
   public:
    A(){}
    struct Fields {
        int noOfPkts;
        } f;
};
template <class T>
Util<T>::Util()
{
}

template <class T>
int Util<T>::GetOperation() const
{
    return operation;
}
template <class T>
struct Fields* Util<T>::GetFields() const
{
    return &mfield.f;
}


int main()
{
auto sn = std::make_unique <Util<A>>();
//sn->GetFields().noOfPkts = 10;
}
```

But I get below compilation error -

```
$ c++ -std=c++14 try51.cpp
try51.cpp: In instantiation of 'Fields* Util<T>::GetFields() const [with T = A]':
try51.cpp:55:1:   required from here
try51.cpp:47:17: error: cannot convert 'const A::Fields*' to 'Fields*' in return
  return &mfield.f;
```

How can I fix both the issue?

Comment: "using temporary as lvalue [-fpermissive]" You try to assign to a temporary. You wouldn't do `int foo() { return 42; } int main() { foo() = 3; }` right?

Comment: The first one is because you return by value. Return a `T&` instead. The second one is because `struct Field` in `Interface` is a different `struct` than in `A`

Comment: Thanks I was able to fix the first issue but what design changes I need to make to fix the second issue?

Comment: Yes modified the same

Comment: `return &mfield.f;`  -->  `return mfield.f;`

Comment: Well it did not fix the issue

Comment: Well, without an error message or your current code ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow format assumes one question per question. Multiple questions in the same question are confusing.

Answer (score 0):

### It is recommended to not ask multiple questions in the same post.

It makes it much more difficult to give you a concise answer.

### To your first question:

The return of `T GetFields()` is a temporary copy of the internal member `mfield`.

The compiler is alerting you helpfully that you are attempting to edit a temporary value.

In order to make this work as coded, you need to update the signature of `T GetFields()` to `T& GetFields()` to cause it to return a *reference* to the internal field, instead of a *copy*.

### To your second question:

You can't do polymorphism like that. The interface doesn't know what a `Fields` is. Pull the Fields struct out of A so everything can see it properly, and/or make it part of the template parameters.

Update: Upon discussing things in the comments, it would appear you are trying to architect your data structures inside out, and that just won't compile.

In this specific case, the data structure specified in class `A` has the Type `A::Fields`, but `Interface` specifies that `Interface::GetFields()` returns the address of an object of type `Fields` of which `A::Fields` is not.

In order to make your current configuration work you would need to make `A::Fields` a class derived from `Fields`, and if you have another class `B` which defines a specific `Fields` struct, it will necessitate any function calling `Interface::GetFields()` to perform Run Time Type Introspection (RTTI) using `dynamic_cast` or `typeid` to determine whether it has a `A::Fields` or a `B::Fields` prior to accessing its members, so as to avoid reading outside the memory of the data structure and triggering a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks the first issue got solved - please let me know how to solve the other one

Comment: Thanks but each template instance will have its own fields structure - so GetFIelds should return based upon the object type - for template parameter can you please provide an example

Comment: To clarify, what else is `A` supposed to do that it cannot be the fields struct itself?

Comment: The Util class will be instantiated for each class having its own fields structure. A was one of that type

Comment: Well, the main issue here is that the interface doesn't know what the `Fields` class is, and the compiler has no way of resolving the Type, and there's basically no way to work around that effectively. Even if you make `Fields` an interface, anything calling GetFields() is going to have to type-check the return in order to know what it actually has.

Comment: I don't think I can give you any more advice with the information I currently have about the goals of your design.